# Is there a way to add a suggested edit as a comment?

Tags: support, editing, comments

Just came across a suggested edit for [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/4590/33), which would fit better as a comment.  Is there a way to convert the edit to a comment, while leaving the original answer alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't.

Reject the edit with the "should be a comment reason".

If it was a registered user they'd see the rejection and hopefully act on it.

As it's an anonymous edit all you can do is post it as a comment yourself (if you think it's valid).

Comment: Wait. Anonymous users can edit, but new *registered* users cannot post pictures?  What a wacky system.

Comment: @Tester101 - well I don't think anonymous users can post pictures either. And it's only suggesting edits :)